# How to use Postman to call Azure AD B2C protected function?

Tags: azure-functions, postman, azure-ad-b2c

How can Postman be used to access an Azure Function with authentication turned on? After choosing Authorization > Type = OAuth 2.0, it is unclear where all of the values in the "Get new access token" screen come from.

Is this the correct method to access the protected function? Authentication has been enabled using Azure AD B2C.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns regarding this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the "Get new access token" feature in postman to access the protected function.

[image]

Grant Type: `Implicit`

Callback URL: `Any URL defined in your B2C app`

Auth URL: `https://{b2ctenant}.b2clogin.com/{b2ctenant}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p={policy}`

ClientID: `Application ID from your b2c app`

Scope: `https://{b2ctenant}.onmicrosoft.com/api/user_impersonation`. You can find it under Published scopes, remember to add it in the API access list, or you will have no permission to access.

[image]

State: `It can be empty`

Client Authentication: `Either one, it doesn't matter`